# Accessing nested classes from an instance created by the parent in C#

Tags: c#, .net

I'm having some trouble with class hierarchy in C#. I have looked around and tried a few things but I can't find any reason why this isn't working, perhaps I just don't understand the visibility of nested classes.

```
class Settings
{
    class Graphics
    {
        class Resolution
        {
            public int Width { get; set; }
            public int Height { get; set; }
        }

        public Resolution Resolution = new Resolution();
        public bool VSync { get; set; }
    }

public Graphics Graphics = new Graphics();

    public Settings()
    {
    // Graphics.Resolution is not visible here, nor is Graphics.VSync;
    }
}
```

I want Graphics and Resolution nested because I don't want them to be accessible from anywhere other than through Settings.

Comment: Your code has other problems - such as the member `Resolution` being declared twice in `Graphics`. I suspect you just want to make `Resolution` internal, but until you can show your *actual code* where only the accessibility is the problem, it's hard to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [default accessibility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ba0a1yw2.aspx) of an inner class is `private`.

Change it to `public` or `internal` to gain access outside the encompassing class.

---

An unrelated issue in your code is that you are declaring members with the same name - `Resolution` and `Graphics` are both class names and other members (property and field, respectively).

Comment: This, plus you cannot have a member with the same name as a nested class. He needs to rename his `Graphics` variable too since there is a nested class with the same name.

Comment: That will expose Graphics.Resolution, but Graphics.VSync remains invisible, as does Resolution.Width and Height. Oh jeez, names? Really? I swear I made Resolution camel case at some point and it didn't change much, but that actually seems to be the issue. I'm surprised Visual Studio didn't throw a tantrum over that.

Comment: @UncleDave - Well, yes, for a similar reason. The `Graphics` class is _also_ `private` - any member of `Graphics` will not be visible outside of it.